# MSBuild Paramaters.xml xpath appsettings file attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xpath, msbuild, msdeploy

Im using msbuild to create a web deploy package using the parameters.xml file to replace web.config settings.

Im trying to replace the appsettings file attribute in web.config

This is my parameters.xml:

```
<parameter name="ClientConfig" description="Please enter the clients config file name." defaultValue="Niad.config" tags="">
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/setting[@name='file']/value" />
 </parameter>
```

This is my Web.config section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings file="Client.config">
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I know I'm writing the xpath match incorrectly, I was hoping someone could help me with the correct syntax.

Comment: /configuration/appSettings/@file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
match="/configuration/appSettings/@file"

<parameter name="ClientConfig" description="Please enter the clients config file name." defaultValue="Niad.config" tags="">
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/@file" />
</parameter>
```